# Implement In-App Facebook-like notifications

Tags: android, facebook, notifications

I am developing a photo sharing application in android and I need to implement real time in-app notification module **exactly** like Facebook notifications. My server is java based. All I come across on the internet is push/pull-notifications, but I'm not sure if they are the way to go for my requirement.

I have decided that I should create a database of notifications in which I can store notifications for every user, and keep the notifications saved for 1 week. Then I can share these notifications with clients using push notifications. But since I'm a beginner, I need expert advice.

Thanks in anvance. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you to use GCM, Google Cloud Messaging, it will do all the hard things for you.

You only need to send a request to GCM restful webservice after any special event. for more info I guess it's better to read this :
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: GCM is responsible for only sending the notification to the devices. My question is that am I right about creating a database for notifications for every user?

Comment: Well, of course if you don't want to send the notification one by one. You need to keep them in a table and then you can set up a cron job in your server and send them all in one group every week. And if you remove the records after you sent the notifications your table will not become big and it gives you a better performance. In case you need to keep a record of sent notifications you can move them to another table, archived sent notification table.